# how can I import a set of strings inside a param

Tags: python

I am trying to scrap some info from a web and if I do it like below, it works

```
import urllib,urllib2

url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists/'
file_res = open('cytoscape.txt','w')

params = {
'from':'ACC',
'to':'GENENAME',
'format':'tab',
'query':'P13368 P20806 Q9UM73 P97793 Q17192'
}
```

If you look at `query`it is tab delimited input in the above case 5 inputs

Now I try to import a data with 10000 input so I made a text file called `data.txt`

As an example I paste this in a txt file and call it `test.txt`

```
'Q92828 O60907 O75376 O15143 O15144 O15145 P61158 P61160 P59998 O15511'
```

and then I try to import it

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
params = {
'from':'ACC',
'to':'GENENAME',
'format':'tab',
'query': 'f'
}
```

where I am always getting error. any idea, how I can do this?

I am getting this error

> params = {
>            ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: ... *what* error?

Comment: @jonrsharpe IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Well just look at the code you've posted: the assignment to params is clearly not indented correctly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how can I then correct it? I have tried 100 things but seems I cannot figure it out

Comment: ...indent it? Please read an introductory Python tutorial; whitespace *matters*.

Comment: @nik params should be indented

Comment: @jonrsharpe my input is indent (each string is separate a space) I dont have problem with parsing 10 or 20 but when it comes to 10000 then I prefer to load a data, you know what I mean?

Comment: @Zafi   `data.txt`
 is indent (each spring is separated from another one by a space)

Comment: If anything, you're making things *less* clear. Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]. As it stands, you appear to have a trivial typo, which makes this a pretty useless question for SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe added above

Comment: No, a [mcve]. And your Python is still indented incorrectly, which is why you're being told it's indented incorrectly. What is unclear?

Comment: @jonrsharpe how can I share the test.txt ??????

Comment: @nik You are inconsistent. In your question you say your query is *tab* delimited, in you comment you say the data in your file is separated by *spaces*. Also you seem confusing the terms `to intend` and `to separate`. In Python some line have to be *indented* by spaces (the line starts with spaces) where other languages would use braces. Your data is (probably) not indented but *separated* by spaces.

Comment: You don't need to, the content of the text file is not relevant to the problem you appear to be asking about. **You have intended `params` incorrectly.**

Comment: @Robin Koch thanks for your answer!! The problem is that i don't know how to make it `indented` don't you think if I knew this, I would ask here ???

Comment: @jonrsharpe **how then can I solve it?**

Comment: @nik This: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_(typesetting)

Comment: By indenting it correctly! Heck, any half-decent text editor will do it for you! Like the answer you've already been given shows you how to do! You will absolutely **not** get a Python indentation error based on the content of a file you're simply reading in. I do not understand what your problem is, which is why I keep asking for a [mcve]. Without it, your question makes no sense and is therefore unanswerable. I have wasted enough time on it, best of luck.

Comment: @nik I showed you how to indent your code in my answer. Did you *understand* what indention means? (No offense, but it's still unclear.)

Comment: @nik, Simply put, after each `:` in your code use `SPACE` *4 (or `TAB` *1)

Comment: @Andersson Thank you ! I accepted the answer below. I think I was more focusing on the input rather than formatting it and `jonrsharpe`made me more confused instead guiding me toward the solution :-D

Comment: Don't blame me for your inability to google "indentation", please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your *python code* has to be indented correctly.
2. Your query in your code is just the string `f` an neither the file nor the content of the file.

Try:

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    params = {            # this statement has to be indented one level
        'from':'ACC',     # these lines are indented just for readability
        'to':'GENENAME',
        'format':'tab',
        'query': f.read() # this actually reads the content of the file
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. I get the same error. paste this in a file named  `text.txt` file  `'Q92828 O60907 O75376 O15143 O15144 O15145 P61158 P61160 P59998 O15511'` and then run your solution

Comment: There *have to be* four spaces in front of `params = {` and the closing `}`. That's what indention means. That's basically the first thing you should know about Python. (Disclaimer: I know it don't *has* to be 4 spaces, I'm simplifying.)

Comment: OH MY GOD! I have been KILLINg Myself to understand the problem. THANKS, THANKS :-D I liked and accepted your answer

Comment: Glad I could help. [More about indention in Python](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php)

Comment: this is crazy, actually I am not using any interpreter (I code in sublime because I could not find a good interpreter for Mac and I did not pay attention to this. Thanks today I learn something :-)) thanks again

Comment: You are confusing terms again. You use an `interpreter` every time you run Python code. What you don't use is an `IDE` (= "Integrated Development Environment") that supports you by showing such errors during development.